# Resolving multiple records where calculations are involved

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table for invoices where the occasional slip-up has led to two invoices being created for certain records. This means I have ~2000 invoice records made up of two rows. I need to merge these duplicate records

Each row has the following information amongst others:

- A key field: `LINK`
- A total, minus VAT field: `ExVAT`
- A VAT field: `VAT`
- A type field: `TYPE`

I've drafted some pseudo-code already, but I'm not very good at VB, so it's in C#:

```
foreach Row record in TableName
  { 
    if (record1.TYPE == "priorfee", record2.TYPE == "priorfee")
      {
         Row newRecord = new Row;
         newRecord.LINK = record1.LINK;
         newRecord.TYPE = record1.TYPE;

         newRecord.VAT = (record1.VAT + record2.VAT);
         newRecord.ExVAT = (record1.ExVAT + record2.ExVAT);

         record1 = Null;
         record2 = Null;
      }
    else if (record1.TYPE == "subsequentfee", record2.TYPE == "subsequentfee")
      {
         Row newRecord = new Row;
         newRecord.LINK = record1.LINK;
         newRecord.TYPE = record1.TYPE;

         newRecord.VAT = (record1.VAT + record2.VAT);
         newRecord.ExVAT = (record1.ExVAT + record2.ExVAT);

         record1 = Null;
         record2 = Null;
      }
   }
```

Now, I need to get this into a working VB script, or figure out a way to do it as an SQL script (I don't mind doing them in two rounds, one per type).

Also, which is more advisable?

Comment: your listing is incomplete. how do you obtain record1 and record2?

Comment: @zaitsman I'm assuming I'd just use an SQL statement to find multiple records, such as the one that the duplicate records wizard creates. This is why I need the `TYPE` definition, as some records have both a `priorfee` and a `subsequentfee` entry. Where this is the case, I do *not* want to merge them. I only want to merge when more than one record of the same `type` exists.

Comment: i'm not sure what a duplicate records wizard is in this case. The problem with your scenario as described is that it will only work if you have a total of 4 duplicated records in the db - 2 with 'priorfee' and 2 with 'subsequentfee'. For example, if you have 20 invoices with type='priorfee', which ones are duplicate of the others?

Comment: @zaitsman The problem is, all these duplicates have the same `LINK` reference. The amount of duplicates varies, and not all records have duplicates. In total, there are 1,016 records that have a duplicate of one type and/or the other, and some of these records have more than one duplicate.

I *could* separate the records into two tables (`priorfee` and `subsfee`), would that make the process easier?

To answer your question, if there are 20 records of type `priorfee`, those records that have the same `LINK` reference are duplicates.

Comment: Just one more thing - your code listing specifies that you want to create NEW records, not update existing, is that correct?

Comment: @zaitsman also, I was referring to a wizard in MS-Access that creates an SQL query to locate duplicates in a specific table, based on one or more distinct columns.

Comment: @zaitsman In this case, yes. Ideally I'd update them, but it would also mean deleting the row that wasn't updated, which I think would over-complicate things in this case.

Comment: is db SQL or Access? i don't have much experience with the latter unfortunately

Comment: Cap you post an output of your duplicate record

Comment: @Shell um... not really. I'm working with confidential data, there's too much identifiable info. I'm confused as to why you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I wrote my first Access query :P

Based on your requirements, this will SUM ALL invoice VATs and ExVATs, take the first LINK and TYPE, based on duplicate LINK and TYPE and INSERT new rows to your db.

Note: this will NOT delete the rows operated on. this will also NOT affect the rows that have no duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO TableName ( TYPE, LINK, VAT, ExVAT )
SELECT TableName.TYPE, TableName.LINK, Sum(TableName.VAT) AS VAT, Sum(TableName.ExVAT) AS ExVAT
FROM TableName
WHERE (((TableName.TYPE)='subsequentfee'))
GROUP BY TableName.TYPE, TableName.LINK
HAVING (((Count(TableName.LINK))>1));
```

To switch between **priorfee** and **subsequentfee**, just update the string variable (or copy paste the query twice)